# Question on basic property of definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Sorry if this is a trivial question.

We of course have the basic property that if $c\in[a,b]$, $$\int_a^bf(x) \, dx = \int_a^cf(x) \, dx+\int_c^bf(x) \, dx.$$ The question that I have is, is there any way at all to simplify an expression of the form $$\int_a^cf(x) \, dx-\int_c^bf(x) \, dx.$$

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In general, I don't think so. It's like taking an arbitrary function and flipping the area over the x-axis after point $c$. There's no symmetry.

Comment: In general, no. Why would there be? $f(x)$ for $x \leq c$ has nothing to do with $f(x)$ for $x > c.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\int_a^cf(x) \, dx-\int_c^bf(x) \, dx$. We know that $-\int_c^bf(x) \, dx = \int_b^cf(x) \, dx$ because when you reverse the order of the bounds, you also reverse the order you subtract values to find the area, which makes the area negative. So, we get $\int_a^cf(x) \, dx-\int_c^bf(x) \, dx = \int_a^cf(x) \, dx + \int_b^cf(x) \, dx $.

Answer (score 2):

The most short answer is no, because the $-$ sign can be interpreted as $\int_{b}^{c}f(x) dx$.

It follows of the property $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=-\int_{b}^{a} f(x)dx$

Which is clearly not compartible of the initial proposition for the sum of integrals in some interval.

Answer (score 2):

try and define a function as an antiderivative:
$$F(t)-F(0)=\int_0^tf(x)dx$$
so:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$$
$$\int_a^cf(x)dx+\int_c^bf(x)dx=[F(c)-F(a)]+[F(b)-F(c)]=F(b)-F(a)$$
so that defines your top property, now:
$$\int_a^cf(x)dx-\int_c^bf(x)dx=[F(c)-F(a)]-[F(b)-F(c)]=2F(c)-[F(a)+F(b)]$$
so in short, no there is not a nice way to define this in terms of your first expression